# How to update two attributes in mysql depending on other attibute using CASE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

How can I update two columns in MySQL depending on a value of another column ?

This is my query so far:

```
UPDATE conversation
SET CASE WHEN user_id = 100 
         THEN user_status='true'
         WHEN pro_user_id=100
         THEN pro_user_status='true'
         ELSE NULL
     END 
WHERE conv_id=12
```

I'm using php progamming language.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: what are the datatypes of `user_status` and `pro_user_status` fields?

Comment: check for errors with the appropriate handler you're using to connect with, which is unknownst to us.

Comment: @TomRegner   I want to update user_status if user id(100) match with user_id  and if user id(100) math with pro_user_id then update pro_user_status

Comment: @Brijeshkumar Did sagi's answer solve the question? If not, you will need to place a comment under the answer as to why it's not working. You tagged as php but no code to support the question. If sagi's answer is the solution as far as the (SQL) syntax goes, then something may be failing you such as the connection used, the way you're querying, etc. It could be anything.

Comment: Have you tried executing the same code through command line (or phpmyadmin)? Does this executes there and not in PHP. Is this issue pertaining to SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't conditionally decide which column to update, so just update the column if it meets the criteria , if not , keep the value it had before :

```
UPDATE conversation 
SET user_status = CASE WHEN user_id = 100
                       THEN 'true'
                       ELSE user_status
                  END,
    pro_user_status = CASE WHEN pro_user_id = 100 
                           THEN 'true'
                           ELSE pro_user_status
                      END
WHERE conv_id=12
```

Comment: "meats" and "meets" are ironically enough, two different animals ;-)

Comment: :D , An honest mistake .. @Fred-ii-

Comment: *hehe* it was fun though ;-)

Comment: I pinged the OP earlier, but alas.... nothing. I have time to make me another cup of coffee then.

Comment: I saw that; I revisited the question earlier. Glad to see it was resolved ;-) *Cheers*